# Can Office Add-Ins function if port 80 and 443 are blocked?

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

My customer is in the banking and finance industry. According to them some of their customers have a highly secure environment. They in-fact block multiple network ports including 80. (I am not sure about 443). The question I have is what are the port restrictions or constraints for an office web add-in? Also, I am assuming that the manifest url can pretty much point to any HTTP or HTTPS url even if the application is running on a different port number?

Answer (score 2):

Office Web Add-ins require a secure HTTP connection (i.e. HTTPS). Normally this would be handled over `443` but that is just the standard port. Which port you host it on however is entirely up to you.

There is, however, a slew of HTTP calls you do not control. There are validation checks, API telemetry, backend services, etc. that are all made over port `443`. Blocking these would produce unpredictable results. If you truly cannot make outbound web calls then you should likely focus on the legacy COM/VSTO stack which doesn't require any remote assets.

That said, it is *extremely* uncommon for organizations to block outbound connections over `80` or `443` since that effectively means they can't browse the web at all. I can't imagine an organization signing up for Office 365 while simultaneously blocking their employees from accessing the internet.